# how to add a button next to a message in java builder

Tags: java, android, sqlite, buffer, builder

Kinda new to Java programming, And I am trying to create a native app for android. 
my problem is, that when I select some stuff from my SQLite DB - I want to add a button with an eventlistener next to the output.

```
    if(view==btnViewAll)
     {
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM catalogue", null);
        if(c.getCount()==0)
        {
            showMessage("Error", "No records found");
            return;
        }
        StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            buffer.append("Product name: "+c.getString(1)+"\n");
            buffer.append("Description: "+c.getString(2)+"\n");
            buffer.append("Price: "+c.getString(3)+"\n");
            buffer.append("Image: "+c.getString(4)+"\n\n");

        }
        showMessage("All Products", buffer.toString());
     }//end of btnViewAll
```

and then my ShowMessage is this -

```
public void showMessage(String title, String message) {
    Builder builder = new Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}//end of Message!
```

This all pops up on my phone, with a list of the records in my DB - but I can't figure out, how to add a button for each row in there.

help is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you'd like to display a list of all records of your DB in a different row, with each row containing the text + a button, right?

Comment: exactly! - so example - user 1 has a name and a phone number, and a button next to him.
and so does user 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering to your recent comment, what you need instead of displaying the full String is to create a custom list and populate it via your DB.
Here are the steps required :

1) Create an Object User, with name/phone number

2) When parsing your DB, return a list

3) Create a CustomAdapter extending ArrayAdapter

4) Change your xml so that there's only a listView

5) In your activity, call an AsyncTask to fetch your DB (as you probably already do), then use the List to populate the ListView through the Adapter.

Further tips : create a layout `row.xml` that'll be inflated in your Adapter, where you'll have the Widgets needed to display informations about your user (ie name/phone n°) + a button. And in the getView of the adapter, inflate your `row.xml`, update the values with the data, and set the behaviour for the button there.

Here's a great tutorial where you'll find everything in details : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Good luck with it !

Comment: So it is not possible to add a button through the builder? because I like the way that I have it now - though I can see upsides to what you're saying!

Comment: What you have actually is a big string containing all the information, + a little bit of arrangement with "\n"'s
So having buttons in there is non-sense as you're printing a full String, not say a TextView + a Button multiple times.